# Can Microsoft Speech SDK 5.4 recognize Russian language?

Tags: speech-recognition, microsoft-speech-api

I'm trying to create a speech-to-text app which can recognize Russian voice.
But I don't know about support for Russian language in Microsoft Speech SDK 5.4.

Can you tell me about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check available language packs here

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224

Russian is supported